# How do I type a class that has the same properties as an object?

Tags: typescript

I want to assign all the properties of an object to a class in it’s constructor. How would I type this class?

```ts
export class CssVars<T extends Record<string,number|string>> {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] // I tried this, but got an error

  constructor(obj: T) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      this[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }
}

const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: '2',
}

const t = new CssVars(obj)
```

`t` should have the type `{ a: number; b: string; }`.

Comment: Hi lanten, I’ve edited your question to better clarify what you’re trying to achieve. Feel free to [edit] it if I’ve interpreted it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there doesn’t seem to be a type-safe way of doing this. You could work around it by doing something like this:

```ts
export type CssVars<T extends Record<string, number | string>> = T

export const CssVars = class <T extends Record<string, number | string>> {
  constructor(obj: T) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      (this as unknown as T)[key] = obj[key]
    }
  }
} as new <T extends Record<string, number | string>>(obj: T) => CssVars<T>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBnDA1AhlDAHgBU5QZgA7AEwzgCVgBjaawjGKAS0oHMAaOJQCuAWwBGwKHAA+cDtz4A+JXAC8cYgCgtoSLDgtKHdFjwF1hgDa4scEmRAUadRiyhsFPAULGTpcl7KqgDeWnCGEMacwkww0AAUEOIAVgBcmgCUcGEREQBm0HAJRiYA1sCIcDxwySnZuXkRCTAAFlx0tnDClGWUEADulHBdxJkA2hWIALqWdZOV0+F5AL7LaysjdJTAA-ak5FS0DMys7JzegiISUrLyF8FJqRlj6qqYOPhExEo6WqXwOqWRq4DIARn4y3EGQA5AAmGGQtb-KImeAaHZ7D7mDBPepAA)